# Unable to retrieve the values SharedPreferences from different extends

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sharedpreferences

I am trying to pass the value of matrix_id from MainActivity(extends Activity) to HomeActivity(extends Activity) and ScheduleFragment(extends Fragment). 
When I run the apps, it will crash.

Im really amateur in Java Programming.

What should I do ?

Please help me, thank you.

This is part of MainActivity.java

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME="PreferencesValue";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    b = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);  
    matrix_id = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtMatric);


    b.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
            editor.putString("matrix", matrix_id.getText().toString());

            editor.commit(); 

            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), HomeActivity.class);
    startActivity(i);
    finish();
        }
       });
      }
```

This is part of HomeActivity.java

```
     /**
 * Displaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
 * */
private void displayView(int position) {
    // update the main content by replacing fragments
    Fragment fragment = null;
    switch (position) {
    case 0: fragment = new ScheduleFragment();
        break;

    case 1: fragment = new ReminderFragment();
        break;

    case 2: fragment = new AboutFragment();
        break;

    case 3: fragment = new LogoutFragment();
        break;
            }
```

This is ScheduleFragment.java

```
    public class ScheduleFragment extends Fragment {
private final Context context;


public static final String PREFS_NAME="PreferencesValue";

public ScheduleFragment(Context context){
    this.context = context;

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_schedule, container, false);

    TextView tvmatrix = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textViewMatrix);

    SharedPreferences settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);

    tvmatrix.setText(settings.getString("matrix", "A324142"));



    return rootView;

 }
  }
```

Comment: Add the log trace here.

Comment: When your app crashes, add the log from logcat. It will tell the exact  exception due to which app crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have

```
public ScheduleFragment(Context context){
this.context = context;
}
```

Fragment constructor must not have any args. You can use `getActivity()` to get the activity context of the activity that hosts the fragment

```
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
```

Comment: Fragment constructor cannot bring any value ?

Comment: @ultra_buckner its is wrong to have a constructor for a fragment with args. just use `getActivity()` and remove the constructor

Comment: but getActivity() got an error in the class extends Fragment.

Comment: @ultra_buckner no that won't give you error. Post the error.

Comment: dude, its my mistake, thank you very much man, 
how I want to +rep u ?
did u have any blog/website for android tutorial ?

Comment: Can I request your help to take a look at my coding ?